# DAX How to compare total sales of chosen period vs total sales 2019 for the same period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a DAX measure that will return the percentage of the **sales diff on 2019%**

So if in the slicer we choose in the slicer **year** 2021, and in the slicer for **month** we choose January and February, we will need to get that period vs same period 2019 in %. If we choose in the slicers 2019 Jan and Feb we should get **0** for **sales vs 2019**.

I cannot create calculated columns. I am only available to create calculated measures.
I have Period[Date], [year],[month], month number.. table and a Sales table.

Any assistance or guidance please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PARALLELPERIOD` function:

```
Sales % of 2 years ago =

VAR SalesThisYear = 
    MySalesMeasure

VAR Sales2YearsAgo =
    CALCULATE ( 
        MySalesMeasure, 
        PARALLELPERIOD ( MyDateTable[Date], -2, YEAR ) 
    )

RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        SalesThisYear, 
        Sales2YearsAgo 
    )
```

Use your table / column names, and existing Sales measure, as required